# Loop through workbook slicer names using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have tried Googling and searching for this one but just can't quite get it. All I am trying to do is loop through the slicers on an activeworksheet and delete the slicer if it exists.

At the moment I have 6 slicers sitting there. Previously I had

```
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Market Segment Name 2", "Line of Business 2" _
    , "Customer Name", "Product Group Name", "Product Type Name", "Product Code") _
    ).Select
    Selection.Delete
```

But this was no good if I had already deleted the slicers.

Now I am trying (note wb is set as a global variable in a module named "Public")

```
Option Explicit
Dim sl As Slicer
Dim slName As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

For Each sl In wb.SlicerCaches
    If sl.Name = "Market Segment Name 2" Or _
        sl.Name = "Line of Business 2" Or _
        sl.Name = "Customer Name" Or _
        sl.Name = "Product Group Name" Or _
        sl.Name = "Product Type Name" Or _
        sl.Name = "Product Name" Then
        slName = sl.Name
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(slName).Delete
    End If
Next sl
```

To me it seems like it should work. I have gotten it to work if I go down to SlicerItem level but I just can't figure out how to access it at Slicer level...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

If this fails I will have a go at building the array and deleting that way but I would still need a way of testing whether the slicer currently exists or not.

Comment: `I just can't figure out how to access it at Slicer level...` I didn't get your quesiton

Comment: Hi Siddharth Rout. I am hoping I have the structure and logic right on this one. I am going by the image (linked below). When I see the slicer on the worksheet I am assuming that is the 'slicer' level and that is where I would access the names so I can detect whether I can delete it or not... http://blogs.office.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-00-44-metablogapi/0636.image_5F00_2ADE6206.png

Comment: so do you want the names of all slicers or check if a slicer exists?

Comment: I just want to check if a slicer exists and then delete it if it does.

Comment: ok posting an answer....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways that I can think of.

One is the `Force` method. Here we don't check if the slicer exists. We simply delete it if it exists. For example

```
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Market Segment Name 2").Delete
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Line of Business 2").Delete
'
'~~> And so on
'
On Error GoTo 0
```

And the other method is to actually check if the slicer exists and then delete it. For example

```
Dim sl As SlicerCache

On Error Resume Next
Set sl = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Market Segment Name 2")
On Error GoTo 0

If Not sl Is Nothing Then sl.Delete

'For Each sl In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    'Debug.Print sl.Name
'Next
```

**EDIT**:

Followup from comments.

Converting the first code into a loop.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sSlicers As String
    Dim Myar
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Slicers you want to delete
    sSlicers = "Market Segment Name 2,Line of Business 2"
    sSlicers = sSlicers & "," & "Customer Name,Product Group Name"
    sSlicers = sSlicers & "," & "Product Type Name,Product Code"

    '~~> Split the names using "," as a delimiter
    '~~> If your slicer names have "," then use a different delimiter
    Myar = Split(sSlicers, ",")

    For i = LBound(Myar) To UBound(Myar)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Myar(i)).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddarth Rout. For now I think I will go with this first option as it gets the job done (which is similar to what I had originally if I had of wrapped it in the "On error Resume Next". I'll hold out for a bit and see if someone can come up with a looping answer as possibly my worksheet may get a lot more slicers and I don't want to have to manually add them all into the code. Thanks again though, it helps to talk to people about these issues.

Comment: I can give you a looping code as well but then you will have to store those names somewhere?

Comment: @JayKilleen: See the edit in the above answer. You may have to refresh the page

Comment: Excellent thanks Siddarth. I might possibly store the data in a userform so users can select which slicers they would like to add based on the fields in the access database. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another peice of code I have finally figured out to do what I was originally trying to achieve.

```
Sub LoopSlicerNames()

Dim slCaches As SlicerCaches
Dim slCache As SlicerCache

Set slCaches = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches

For Each slCache In slCaches

    'MsgBox (slCache.Name & " is used for " & slCache.PivotTables.Item(1).Name)
    If slCache.PivotTables.Item(1).Name = "PTDashboard" Then
        slCache.Delete
        'MsgBox ("Slicer has been deleted")
    End If

    'If slCache.Name = "Slicer_Market_Segment_Name2" Then slCache.Delete

Next slCache

End Sub
```

The difference with this one is that I targeted the slicer based on its parent pivottable being on the worksheet so I wouldn't need to add the exact name of the slicer into the code. If I did want to add the name of the slicer into the code I can just switch around the commenting.

Thanks again Siddarth. You got me over the initial hurdles and provided good solutions. I think my initial problem was thinking that the slicer was the child of the slicercache. Looking into it now it seems to go slicerCaches, SlicerCache then SlicerItem and the 'slicer' as I referred to in my original question was the 'SlicerCache' level... so that picture I linked just confused the hell out of me haha.